# How to reset the UIPickerview selectRow to default zero row

Tags: swift

I have an application with `UIPickerview` with 2 components, taking the data from 2 arrays. I have set the second component on row 3 when the row 1 in component 0 is selected. That was fine, but my problem is when the `row` in component 0 changes, I want the component 1 to be reset to row 0 (as a default).

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!

let firstArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let secondArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myPicker.delegate = self
    myPicker.dataSource = self
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    switch component {
    case 0: return firstArray.count
    case 1: return secondArray.count
    default: break
    }
    return 0
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch component {
    case 0: return firstArray[row]
    case 1: return secondArray[row]
    default: break
    }
    return ""
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if myPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 1 {
        myPicker.selectRow(3, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `else if` to select first `row` in `component` `1` as,

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if myPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 1 {
        myPicker.selectRow(3, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
    } else if component == 0 {
        myPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. that worked fine, but the problem is when I select row 1 in component 0, the picker rolls the component 1 to row 3 and stick (can't move). I want it to automatically roll to row 3 but I want to be able roll it myself.

Comment: Additionally, can I make reverse relation? means if I select row 3 in component 1, the component 0 picker reset to row 1, but I should be able to roll it myself to any other row.